# How to use react-hooks with Jest and react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm having an issue with testing component which is using react hooks.
I need to test if after clicking a button the date range inside the ant design range picker is being updated. For testing I'm using Jest and react-testing-library.

At this point it looks like this: (some of these nested components are just styled-components :) )

Parent.jsx:

```
 const Parent = () => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([moment(), moment()]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar
        visible={sidebarVisible}
        setSidebarVisible={setSidebarVisible}
        setTableData={setTableData}
        setStatementsLength={setStatementsLength}
        setDateRange={setDateRange}
        dateRange={dateRange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Sidebar.jsx:

```js
const Sidebar = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Drawer
        placement="left"
        closable={false}
        onClose={() => props.setSidebarVisible(false)}
        visible={props.visible}
        width={488}
        bodyStyle={drawerStyle}
      >
        <DrawerContent data-test-id="statementsSidebar">
          <DrawerHeader data-test-id="statementsSidebarHeader">
            {t('settlements.statements.sidebar.createQuery')}
          </DrawerHeader>
          <DrawerBody>
            <DateSelect
              dateRange={props.dateRange}
              setDateRange={props.setDateRange}
            />
          </DrawerBody>
          <DrawerFooter/>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

DateSelect.jsx:

```js
const DateSelect = props => {
  const RangePicker = DatePicker.RangePicker;
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const timeUnit = Object.freeze({ day: 'd', week: 'w', month: 'm' });
  const [offsetUnit, setOffsetUnit] = useState(timeUnit.day);

  const setRangeToLastWeek = () => {
    if (offset > 0) {
      props.setDateRange([
        moment().subtract(1, 'w'),
        moment().add(offset, 'd'),
      ]);
    } else if (offset < 0) {
      props.setDateRange([
        moment()
          .subtract(1, 'w')
          .add(offset, 'd'),
        moment(),
      ]);
    } else {
      props.setDateRange([moment().subtract(1, 'w'), moment()]);
    }
    setOffsetUnit('w');
  };

 const manuallySetDate = range => {
    setOffset(0);
    props.setDateRange(range);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderRow/>
      <DateSelectorRow>
          <ButtonsColumn>
            <Button
              value="lastWeek"
              onClick={setRangeToLastWeek}
              style={styleButtonPadding}
              data-test-id="setRangeToLastWeek"
              data-testid="lastWeekButton"
            >
              Last 7 days
            </Button>
          </ButtonsColumn>
        <div data-testid="range-picker-value">
        <RangePicker
          value={props.dateRange}
          format={DateFormat}
          onChange={v => manuallySetDate(v)}
        />
        </div>
      </DateSelectorRow>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateSelect;
```

DateSelect.test.js:

```js
 it('After clicking last 7 days button date range is changed', () => {
    // const setDateRange = ??????
     const range = [moment(), moment()];
     const { container } = render(<DateSelect setDateRange={setDateRange} dateRange={range}/>);
     const startDate = getByPlaceholderText(container, 'Start date');
     const endDate = getByPlaceholderText(container, 'End date');
     const lastWeekButton = getByTestId(container,'lastWeekButton');
     expect(startDate.value).toBe(moment().format(DateFormat));
     expect(endDate.value).toBe(moment().format(DateFormat));
     fireEvent.click(lastWeekButton);
     expect(startDate).toBe(moment().subtract(1, 'w').format(DateFormat));
     expect(endDate.value).toBe(moment().format(DateFormat));
   });
```

As expected, since I'm not passing the setDateRange function as a prop to DateSelect component inside the test the range value doesn't change. I've tried to add a hook inside the test like this:

```js
const [dateRange, setDateRange] = [moment(), moment()];
```

But I'm getting the: 
**Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**
So I'm guessing I cannot use it there. Is there any solution to this? 
How to specify the `setDateRange` function inside the test that would act like a hook?

I found this: https://github.com/mpeyper/react-hooks-testing-library
But it looks like this is for custom hooks?

Maybe there is a solution to this test case that is without the use of react-hooks? Any ideas highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to render `Parent` since it contains the logic to update `DateSelect`. This makes for a better test because you're testing that the integration among components works.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. But should that be a part of parent test or the DateSelect test than? :)

Comment: Probably parent. TBH I stopped testing components, I test features now. Makes more sense to me

Comment: I'm a begginer to react as well as testing in it so it might take me a while to work things out, but thank you very much for your help :)